# Add QWidget on top of QOpenGLWindow

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qwidget, qwindow

I want to add QWidget on top of my QOpenGLWindow. For example:

In qmainwindow.cpp:

```
QWidget *mywidget = new QWidget(this);
mywidget->hide();

QOpenGLWindow *glwindow = new QOpenGLWindow();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(glwindow, this);

// ...

ui->tabWidget->addTab(container, "Container");

// then I want mywidget to be at the top of my tabWidget and container.
mywidget->show();
```

But **mywidget** is behind the **container**.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Qt cannot divine what Z order you want if you don't create the widgets in Z order. You need to `raise` the widget. The whole hiding rigmarole is completely unnecessary anyway. Simply create the widget where you need it.